# Lubuntu crashes after connected to the wifi

Tags: lubuntu, crash

so I am testing Lubuntu in an old laptop, and the system keeps crashing after I have connected to the wifi and launched Firefox. I am booting using a USB drive, and I have changed Linux config to `quiet splash nomodeset`. Did anyone have the same issue, and what did you do to fix it?
Laptop performance shouldn't be an issue because it runs in 4GB RAM with i5 processor.

Thank you all!

Comment: what do you mean by "crashing"?

Comment: And why are you adding `nomodeset`?

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu? Is the system installed or not? If it's installed, logs would be useful, especially /var/log/syslog. Is there anything in /var/crash? If it's not installed, and you're booting to a live image, have you checked the disc for defects at the boot screen?